# EntityFramework Core select M:N related data

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I seem to have a big misunderstanding of how EF Core / Linq / Navigation Properties work.

I tried to extend my example from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919230/asp-net-core-entityframework-core-left-outer-join-in-linq) adding a m:n relationship.

Database tables:

1. Person {Id (in), Firstname (nvarchar), Lastname (nvarchar) }
2. Group {Id (int), Name (string) }
3. GroupAssignment {Id (int), PersonId (int), GroupId (int) }

Database data:
The person with Id 1 is assigned to the groups 1 and 3.

My query returns as expected the linked GroupAssignments:

```
var result = from person in _dbContext.Person
            select new
            {
                id = person.Id,
                firstname = person.Firstname,
                lastname = person.Lastname,
                groupAssignments = person.GroupAssignment  
            };

return Ok(result);
```

But I want to get a list with the fields of the N table (Groups).
The result I am looking for is

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "First1",
    "lastname": "Last1",
    "groupAssignments": 
    [
         {
         "id": 1,
         "name": "test group 1"
         },
         {
         "id": 3,
         "name": "test group 3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

---

By the way: I would be really happy if you post some good reading links about EF (core) and linq into the comments. It seems I have a lot of beginner problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a `Group` navigation property in `GroupAssigment` entity . If that is the case use `Select` extension method:

```
var result = from person in _dbContext.Person
            select new
            {
                id = person.Id,
                firstname = person.Firstname,
                lastname = person.Lastname,
                groupAssignments= person.GroupAssignment.Select(ga=>ga.Group)  
            };

return Ok(result);
```

About documentation, you can start [here](http://ef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying/index.html).

### Update

To achieve what you commented below you can use an [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) to project only those two properties:

```
groupAssignments= person.GroupAssignment.Select(ga=>new{id=ga.Group.Id,name=ga.Group.Name})
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. This one I knew but unfortunatly it doesn't cover simple stuff like that from the question. It's acutally to less information to get started beyond 101. m:n would be 102 I guess. Your code works great, big thanks but would you mind adding a second code snippet on how to get rid of the <code>"groupAssignment": []</code> so just pick id and name of the group?

Comment: Hi, @monty, take a look my update and let me know if that is what you looking for

Comment: Thank you again. That was exactly what I was looking for. Saved my day an a couple of the following ones.

Comment: Sorry for the late detail but where would I place a group by for the ga.Group.Id to get only one entry if the Person is (for some reason) in the same group twice?

Comment: Figured it out :-)