# Using Entity Framework to return a very specific set of data from MSSQL

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was able to create a .NetCore 2.1 website with Enitity Framework by following a Microsoft tutorial.

The web app connects to a MS SQL Database and uses scaffolding to translate the database tables into classes.

But all it is doing behind the scenes is basic queries like 'select * from myTable' etc.

For example, I have this simple controller that just gets all the Players in the PlayerList table:

```
        // GET: PlayerLists
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.PlayerList.ToListAsync());
    }
```

This one is a little more complicated, but it's really just getting one Player:

```
        // GET: PlayerLists/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var playerList = await _context.PlayerList.FindAsync(id);
        if (playerList == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(playerList);
    }
```

This works, but I need something more complex to get a very specific set of data from my database.

How can I add a query that runs a very specific query with SQL Joins, case statements, and group by clauses?

Thanks!

Comment: Querying is accomplished via LINQ http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF core 2.1 we use Linq to query data.You could see how to use `Joins` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39919230/asp-net-core-entityframework-core-left-outer-join-in-linq) and `group by` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173410/linq-combining-join-and-group-by). The linq equivalent of transact sql CASE WHEN THEN is the conditional operator `?:`

Below is a simple demo which combines them to do the query:

1.Models

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; } 
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

2.Query in controller

```
var result = from p in _context.Products
                     group p by p.CategoryID into pg
                     // join *after* group
                     join c in _context.Categories on pg.FirstOrDefault().CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
                     select new
                     {
                         CategoryName = c.Name == "oldName" ? "newName" : c.Name,//Replace Case statement
                         Products = pg
                     };
```